# Getting data for a specific location from GRIB file

Tags: r, gis, grib, cdo-climate

I want to extract data from a GRIB file, provided from ECMWF, for a specific location using R.

For now, I'm able to get data and export it to .csv but the location seems wrong.
I'm trying to get it for the south of Ireland (lat/long around 50/-8).

When I read the GRIB file in ArcGIS, the data extracted from R doesn't match the data seen in GIS so I assume I did something wrong with the coordinates.

```
library(raster)                           
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

s.area <- extent(c(-10.0,-8.5,51.0,51.5))

    s.area@xmin <- s.area@xmin + 180
    s.area@xmax <- s.area@xmax + 180

    output_as_csv <- function(x, ext, var_name="wave_period", start_date, 
                              output_filename) {
      x.out <- data.frame(lon=NA, lat=NA, var_name=NA, date_time=NA)
      x.out <- x.out[FALSE,]
      for(i in 1:nlayers(x)) {
        x.temp <- x[[i]] %>% 
          crop(ext) %>% 
          rasterToPoints() %>% 
          as.data.frame() %>% 
          mutate(date_time=start_date + hours(i) - hours(1),
                 lat=x - 180,
                 lon=y) %>% 
          dplyr::select(-x, -y)
        names(x.temp)[1] <- var_name
        x.out <- rbind(x.out, x.temp)
      }
      x.out <- x.out %>% 
        unite(lon_lat, lon, lat, remove=TRUE) %>% 
        spread(lon_lat, var_name)
      write.csv(x.out, output_filename, row.names=FALSE)
    }

output_as_csv(x=s, ext=s.area, start_date=start.date, output_filename="Wave period.csv")
```

Comment: Extent is the coordinates (in lat/long) for the south of Ireland

Answer (score 2):

Every time when I am dealing with grib files I prefer to convert them into netCDF using cdo (`cdo -f nc copy infile.grib outfile.nc)`. Then you can use the `raster` package in R. I had problems dealing with grib files and raster package in R before.

Comment: I very much encourage the use of CDO as well. It has one-line build-in functions to handle all sorts of tasks like this. Including selecting an area box and averaging over different dimensions. Check the manual: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf

Comment: I agree, which is why I've now set up the cdo-climate flag for questions such as these which pertain to gridded grib or netcdf file manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the value for a specific location directly from the grib file with CDO nearest neighbour remapping with the lon/lat location operator:

```
cdo remapnn,lon=X/lat=Y input.grb point.grb
```

If you prefer to have the output in netcdf format you can pipe the answer into the copy command, using the -f format option:

```
cdo -f nc copy -remapnn,lon=X/lat=Y input.grb point.nc
```